# Using multiple functions on a row in a select in sql server

Tags: sql-server, function

I've got a timesheet table with an id, and total hours.

I now have a

```
select ts.totalhours, fn_NormalTime(ts.id), fn_Overtime(ts.id) from tsentries ts
```

I have done this improve readability in the original query as well as to centralize logic with regards to holidays, Sunday time, etc.
However, each function in turn now does a `select` from the table to get items like date, rules, etc.
Is there a way to get sql to not redo the retrieve for every function or will internal caching suffice? Looking to improve speed.

Comment: Hello Alaex Welcome on Stackoverflow  Could You Give a EXample with view

Comment: I'd think we'll need to see your functions to advice, but generally speaking - you might be able to combine the functions into a table valued function and then join into that, instead of calling the function per line. As SQL works on sets of data, you might be able to handle it all in a query which then might form the foundation for a view or similar for simplified look up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using functions in the SELECT part of the query will lead to bad performances because the SELECT inside the function will need to be executed for each line you return from your query. There is no way to cache this result this way. The query optimizer will only do a good job if you write all the data retrieval logic inside the same query.